# Drawing border colors during a CSS transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, border

```css
button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #f45e61;
  color: #f45e61;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
button::before, button::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.draw {
  transition: color 0.25s;
}
.draw::before, .draw::after {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: width 1.25s ease-out 1.25s, height 1.25s ease-out 1.25s;

}
.draw::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.draw::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.draw:hover {
  color: #60daaa;
}
.draw:hover::before, .draw:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.draw:hover::before {
  border-top-color: #60daaa;
  border-right-color: #60daaa;
  transition: width 0.25s ease-out, height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
}
.draw:hover::after {
  border-bottom-color: #60daaa;
  border-left-color: #60daaa;
  transition: border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s, width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s, height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s;
}
```

```html
<section class="buttons">
  <button class="draw">Draw</button>
</section>
```

I have a working pen ( https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdgdxO ) that changes the border color of an element while hovering ( top right bottom left ) with some transition to smoothen it up.

I would like to be able to "reverse" the border color change after a few seconds. Basically, I'd like to change border color when the opposite one is changing color :

- border-top change color
- border-right change color
- border-bottom change color & border-top goes back to its original color
- border-left change color & border-right goes back to its original color
- border-top change color & border-bottom goes back to its original color
- border-right change color & border-left goes back to its original color
  etc.

Right now I only have the color change worked out, but I don't know how to "reverse" it. I'd also like this transition to loop forever, but I'm clueless on where to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: loop forever whie on hover?

Comment: Looks to me like more of a job for animation rather than transition! CSS animation gives you the option to loop as Gerardo has suggested.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would use multiple `linear-gradient` and a *complex* animation (by animating size/position of each one) to obtain the final result. If you get the trick you can easily adjust the different values to obtain any animation you want.

```css
.draw {
  padding: 20px 50px;
  outline:none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-image: 
  linear-gradient(#f45e61, #f45e61), 
  linear-gradient(#f45e61, #f45e61), 
  linear-gradient(#f45e61, #f45e61), 
  linear-gradient(#f45e61, #f45e61), 
  
  linear-gradient(#60daaa, #60daaa), 
  linear-gradient(#60daaa, #60daaa), 
  linear-gradient(#60daaa, #60daaa), 
  linear-gradient(#60daaa, #60daaa);
  
  background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 100%, 
                       0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0;
  background-size: 3px 0%, 0% 3px, 0% 3px, 3px 0%,  
                   3px 100%, 100% 3px, 100% 3px,3px 100%;
  background-color:transparent;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:0.2s linear;
}

.draw:hover {
  background-position: 0 100%, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0, 
                       0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0;
  background-size: 3px 0%, 100% 3px, 0% 3px,3px 0%,  
                   3px 100%, 100% 3px, 100% 3px,3px 100%;
  animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite 0.2s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
  background-position: 0 100%, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0, 
                       0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0;
  background-size: 3px 0%, 100% 3px, 0% 3px,3px 0%,  
                   3px 100%, 100% 3px, 100% 3px,3px 100%;
  }
  40% {
  background-position: 0 100%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 
                       0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0;
  background-size: 3px 0%, 100% 3px, 0% 3px,3px 100%,  
                   3px 100%, 100% 3px, 100% 3px,3px 100%;
  }
  60% {
  background-position: 0 100%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 
                       0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0;
  background-size: 3px 0%, 0% 3px, 100% 3px,3px 100%,  
                   3px 100%, 100% 3px, 100% 3px,3px 100%;
  }
  70% {
  background-position: 0 100%, 100% 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 
                       0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0;
  background-size: 3px 100%, 0% 3px, 100% 3px,3px 0%,  
                   3px 100%, 100% 3px, 100% 3px,3px 100%;
  }
  80% {
  background-position: 0% 0%, 0% 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 
                       0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0;
  background-size: 3px 100%, 0% 3px, 0% 3px,3px 0%,  
                   3px 100%, 100% 3px, 100% 3px,3px 100%;
  }
  100% {
  background-position: 0% 0%, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 
                       0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0;
  background-size: 3px 0%, 100% 3px, 0% 3px,3px 0%,  
                   3px 100%, 100% 3px, 100% 3px,3px 100%;  
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="draw">Draw</button>
```

### **How does it work?**

**The structure:** We have 8 `linear-gradient`. 4 will simply create the initial border and won't move (they are placed at the bottom layer) and 4 will be used to draw the line that will create our animation above the initial border (they are placed at the top layer).

The order is important as within background properties we will have 8 values each one for each gradient. You will notice the `3px` value that will simply specify the width or height of each gradient (similar to the `border-width`) and it won't change during the animation.

**The animation:** I will adjust position/size of each gradient to create the animation. it's divided into 2 parts: a small transition and a big animation. The transition is simply used to create the initial state of the animation that's why the duration used for the transition is the same as the delay of the animation.

1. The first step is to animate the **top** border **from left to right**. To do this the gradient should be positioned at `(0,0) [top,left]` with a size of `0% 3px [width height]`. Then I simply change the size to `100% 3px` and I will get the needed animation (the 3px as described before won't change).

   [image]
2. Now to animate the second border we do the same. We need a gradient positioned at `(100%,0) [top,right]` with a size of `3px 0% [width height]` that we animate to `3px 100%`:

[image]

3. Now since we have two borders we need to animate the third one AND hide the first one. I won't detail the third border as it's similar to the above ones so let's see how to hide the top one. The first intuitive idea is to simply set its size back to `0% 3px` but this will simply create the inverse animation and thus we will have a **right to left** animation which is bad. The trick here is to adjust the position of the gradient to make it `(100%,0) [top,right]` instead of `(0,0)` as both positions are equivalent when the gradient is 100% size (so we do this at the previous step when animating the second one). Now, we can put back the size to `0% 3px` and we will have a **left to right** animation:

[image]

4. We continue the same logic until we get back to the initial state and by specifying `infinite` in the animation property we will have the needed effect.

---

So the main Idea is to have a gradient with the size equal to 0% that we animate to full size (100%) in a given direction then we change its position (this won't have any effect on full size) and then animate back its size to 0. We mix this with the 4 gradients we have.

### **UPDATE**

To avoid the confusing with all these gradient here is an update where I used a pseudo element for the static border thus we keep only 4 gradients for the animation:

```css
.draw {
  position:relative;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  outline:none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-image: 
  linear-gradient(#f45e61, #f45e61), 
  linear-gradient(#f45e61, #f45e61), 
  linear-gradient(#f45e61, #f45e61), 
  linear-gradient(#f45e61, #f45e61);
  
  background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 100%;
  background-size: 3px 0%, 0% 3px, 0% 3px, 3px 0%;
  background-color:transparent;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:0.2s linear;
}
.draw:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  border:3px solid #60daaa;
}

.draw:hover {
  background-position: 0 100%, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0;
  background-size: 3px 0%, 100% 3px, 0% 3px,3px 0%;
  animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite 0.2s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
  background-position: 0 100%, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0;
  background-size: 3px 0%, 100% 3px, 0% 3px,3px 0%;
  }
  40% {
  background-position: 0 100%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 0;
  background-size: 3px 0%, 100% 3px, 0% 3px,3px 100%;
  }
  60% {
  background-position: 0 100%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
  background-size: 3px 0%, 0% 3px, 100% 3px,3px 100%
  }
  70% {
  background-position: 0 100%, 100% 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%;
  background-size: 3px 100%, 0% 3px, 100% 3px,3px 0%;
  }
  80% {
  background-position: 0% 0%, 0% 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%;
  background-size: 3px 100%, 0% 3px, 0% 3px,3px 0%;
  }
  100% {
  background-position: 0% 0%, 0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%;
  background-size: 3px 0%, 100% 3px, 0% 3px,3px 0%  
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="draw">Draw</button>
```

Comment: awesome! it's almost what I was looking for! I added an infinite animation loop, the only problem is that the top border doesn't change color when the border-bottom goes back to its original color ( the last item on the color change flow I've mentioned earlier ) 

could you indicate me what I should change your previous code to make it work? there's a lot of value and I don't really get what do they do to be honest

Comment: @JorelAmthor well this is the small drawback :) as when the animation ends all of them disappear so not easy to always have a border shown as at the start there is 0 border  ...but am trying to figure out a trick :) ... by the way the values seems diffcult but simply imagine you have 8 gradient and for each one you have a size and postion all defined in the same property, so remove the animation and play with values to understand how they work :)

Comment: i kinda get it but i have some difficulties to pin point when each border get drawn :/ 

if it helps, it doesn't necessarily have to start at the top right corner !  @Temani Afif

Comment: @JorelAmthor well i will try to add more explanation ;) i know it's a bit tricky :) ... give me few minutes ;)

Comment: @JorelAmthor i found a trick i let you check :) now am gonna write the explanation

Comment: @JorelAmthor added the explanation too ;)

Comment: awesome work ! i wish i could upvote this more ! thanks a bunch

Comment: @JorelAmthor welcome :) i aslo added another update where i used less gradient to make it easier ;) as i know it can be tricky to handle many backgrounds