# CSS3 draw border animation direction

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have a simple box with a draw border animation on it. Each box is supposed to draw the box in a different direction however I'm having an issue controlling the direction of the lines being drawn.

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/015u7xyg/1/).

And code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $(function($, win) {
       $.fn.inViewport = function(cb) {
          return this.each(function(i,el){
            function visPx(){
              var H = $(this).height(),
                  r = el.getBoundingClientRect(), t=r.top, b=r.bottom;
              return cb.call(el, Math.max(0, t>0? H-t : (b<H?b:H)));  
            } visPx();
            $(win).on("resize scroll", visPx);
          });
       };
     }(jQuery, window));
    
     $(".js-fade-in-left").inViewport(function(px){
         if(px) $(this).addClass("o-fade-in-up") ;
     });
    
     $(".js-fade-in-right").inViewport(function(px){
         if(px) $(this).addClass("o-fade-in-up") ;
     });
    
     $(".js-fade-in-down").inViewport(function(px){
         if(px) $(this).addClass("o-fade-in-up") ;
     });
    
     $(".js-fade-in-up").inViewport(function(px){
         if(px) $(this).addClass("o-fade-in-up") ;
     });
    
     $(".js-fade-in").inViewport(function(px){
         if(px) $(this).addClass("o-fade-in") ;
     });
    
     $(".panel-box").inViewport(function(px){
         if(px) $(this).addClass("active") ;
     });
    
     
     
    });
```

```css
    body {
      background:#000000;
      color:white;
    }
    
    
    
    .o-rel {
      position:relative;
    }
    
    .panel-wrapper {
     background-size:cover;
     padding:120px 0;
    }
    .panel-box {
     position:absolute;
     top:50%;
     transform:translateY(-50%);
     border:1px solid white;
     padding:5% 12%;
     width:60%;
     right:-1px;
     border:0;
     background:none;
     z-index:10;
    }
    
    .panel-box::before,
    .panel-box::after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
     }
    
    .panel-box::before {
      top: 0;
        right: 0;
     }
    .panel-box::after {
      left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        
     }
    
    .panel-box.active::before {
       width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         border-top-color: white;
         transition: width 0.25s ease-out, height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
      }
    .panel-box.active::after {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         border-left-color:  white;
         border-bottom-color: white;
         transition: border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s, height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s, width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s ;
      }
     
    
    
    .panel-box-left {
     left:-11px;
     right:auto;
    }
    .panel-box-left::before {
        top: 0;
        right:0;
     }
    .panel-box-left::after {
      
        bottom: 0;
        left:0;
     }
    
    .panel-box-left.active::before {
       width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         border-top-color: white;
         border-right-color: white;
         transition: width 0.25s ease-out, height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
      }
     .panel-box-left.active::after {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         
         border-bottom-color: white;
         border-left-color: white;
         transition: border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s, height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s, width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s ;
      }
    
    .js-fade-in-left {
     opacity: 0;
     transform: translate(-20px, 0px); 
       transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    }
    
    .js-fade-in-right {
     opacity: 0;
     transform: translate(20px, 0px); 
       transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    }
    
    .js-fade-in-down {
     opacity: 0;
     transform: translate(0px, -100px); 
       transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    }
    
    
    .js-fade-in-up {
     opacity: 0;
     transform: translate(0px, 20px); 
       transition: all 0.7s ease-out 0s;
    }
    
    .js-fade-in {
     opacity: 0;
     transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    }
    
    .o-fade-in-up {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translate(0px, 0px); 
    }
    
    .o-fade-in {
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="o-rel panel-wrapper">
      <div class="panel-box">
        <div class="js-fade-in-right">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce in interdum lectus, non auctor diam. Sed maximus mi a quam vestibulum, quis iaculis justo gravida. Morbi sollicitudin augue et quam accumsan commodo. Suspendisse eget dignissim sapien. Cras a eros ac risus rhoncus rhoncus. Curabitur gravida tempor nulla. Aenean id ante eget sapien feugiat varius eget sed velit. Donec eleifend ultrices dui et accumsan. Nam dapibus rhoncus odio nec interdum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent ullamcorper mattis elit.
    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="o-rel panel-wrapper">
    <div class="panel-box panel-box-left">
    <div class="js-fade-in-left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce in interdum lectus, non auctor diam. Sed maximus mi a quam vestibulum, quis iaculis justo gravida. Morbi sollicitudin augue et quam accumsan commodo. Suspendisse eget dignissim sapien. Cras a eros ac risus rhoncus rhoncus. Curabitur gravida tempor nulla. Aenean id ante eget sapien feugiat varius eget sed velit. Donec eleifend ultrices dui et accumsan. Nam dapibus rhoncus odio nec interdum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent ullamcorper mattis elit.
    
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The top/first box I would like to be animated like so

1. top border line animates in from right to left
2. left border line animations from top to bottom
3. bottom border line animations from left to right
4. right border line doesn't need to appear as its offset off screen.

The bottom/second box I would like to be animated like so:

1. top border line animates in from left to right
2. right border line animates in from top to bottom
3. bottom animates in from right to left
4. left border line doesn't need to appear as its offset from screen.

How do I control the direction of the border animation to achieve this?

Comment: a similar quesiton : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48694894/drawing-border-colors-during-a-css-transition/48695388#48695388 will probably give me you more ideas on how to do