# I want to animate a border for my scroll arrow, make it draw itself, instead of just appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As it is now, the border just sort of appears. I would like to make the circular border draw itself, starting from the top. Not sure if I can do this purely with CSS or if I need some jquery. Thanks! Here is my codepen as well 
https://codepen.io/jamesrichardsdesign/pen/eQzjQY

```css
.glyphicon {
    position: relative;
    content:"\e259";
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 2vw;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
}

.glyphicon:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.glyphicon:hover {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></i>
```

Comment: check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48694894/drawing-border-colors-during-a-css-transition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no border animation that you can apply with CSS here, but what you're describing sounds well suited to SVG draw paths. Instead of using a webfont, consider using an SVG icon that has your icon and border. That way you can use CSS to draw the path of the circle on the hover event.

See: https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/