# How to animate a gradient border on input focus?

Tags: html, css, border, css-animations

I am trying to animate a gradient border on input focus. The example below is what I want to achieve, but how can I extend it to a gradient border?

Thanks for any help!

```css
:focus{outline: none;}

.wrapper{position: relative; width:200px}
input[type="text"]{width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box}

.effect-9 ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-9 ~ .focus-border:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.2s; transition-delay: 0.2s;}
.effect-9 ~ .focus-border:after{top: auto; bottom: 0; right: auto; left: 0; transition-delay: 0.6s;}
.effect-9 ~ .focus-border i:before,
.effect-9 ~ .focus-border i:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 2px; height: 0; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.2s;}
.effect-9 ~ .focus-border i:after{left: auto; right: 0; top: auto; bottom: 0; transition-delay: 0.4s;}
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border:after{width: 100%; transition: 0.2s; transition-delay: 0.6s;}
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border:after{transition-delay: 0.2s;}
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border i:before,
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border i:after{height: 100%; transition: 0.2s;}
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border i:after{transition-delay: 0.4s;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="effect-9" type="text">
  <span class="focus-border">
    <i></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: this can probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48695388/8620333 you can do the same with only one elment and background then you can easily adjust the coloration to make it a gradient

Comment: Have you tried background gradient mixed with background-size & position . an old example of mine https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/details/pKwby inspired from https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/HcDFk when SVG was not so handy to use :)

Answer (score 0):

```
:focus{outline: none;}

.wrapper{position: relative; width:500px; }
input[type="text"]{width: 100%; height: 60px; box-sizing: border-box;font-size: 20px; padding: 0 10px;}

.effect-9 ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-9 ~ .focus-border:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 0; height: 2px; background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(75,105,142,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); transition: 0.2s; transition-delay: 0.2s;}
.effect-9 ~ .focus-border:after{top: auto; bottom: 0; right: auto; left: 0; transition-delay: 0.6s;}
.effect-9 ~ .focus-border i:before,
.effect-9 ~ .focus-border i:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 2px; height: 0; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(75,105,142,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); transition: 0.2s;}
.effect-9 ~ .focus-border i:after{left: auto; right: 0; top: auto; bottom: 0; transition-delay: 0.4s;}
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border:after{width: 100%; transition: 0.2s; transition-delay: 0.6s;}
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border:after{transition-delay: 0.2s;}
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border i:before,
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border i:after{height: 100%; transition: 0.2s;}
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border i:after{transition-delay: 0.4s;}
```

check if it is what you are looking for, made some height and width change for visibility