# How to achieve smooth border animation on hover CSS?

Tags: css

I am trying to create a hover animation for a button. On a mouse hover, there should be border transition from left to bottom to right to top. Basically completing the button structure i.e. rectangular.

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove 800ms ;
  transition: all ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  0%{
        border-left: 1px solid;
    }
    25%
    {
    border-left: 1px solid;
border-bottom: 1px solid;
    }
    50%
    {
    border-left: 1px solid;
border-bottom: 1px solid;
        border-right: 1px solid;
    }
    100%
    {
    border-left: 1px solid;
border-bottom: 1px solid;
        border-right: 1px solid;
        border-top: 1px solid;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The @keyframes Rule</h1>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The @keyframes rule is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ymbspr63/

Now, if you see it looks quite awful and doesn't have smoothness. I used transition property as well but that didn't solve the issue. What am I missing here?

I hope everyone understands what I am trying to achieve. :)

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48695388/8620333

Comment: you may inspire yourself from : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/HcDFk , https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pKwby or https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/kpHGv all based on gradient,keyframes,background-size even that is a few years old it still works. today you also have SVG well supported

Comment: @TemaniAfif I saw the post. It pretty much what I am looking for. Though it uses a different method i.e. background property. I loved the explanation given by you. Thank you so much for that. I am trying to understand it more clearly. Also, I tried something myself and achieved this - [link]https://jsfiddle.net/x3hkuyj5/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thank you for linking out some of the examples. This definitely helps. I will try to go through the code and understand it.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think what I am trying to achieve won't happen with border property. Since the border is a full line itself and doesn't have a start and an endpoint. It would appear as a whole line. Oops! Correct me if I am wrong. PS - I think your method seems the way for me.

Answer (score 0):

For a CSS transition to work it has to have 2 specific values to transition between. So for it to transition "smoothly" it needs to have a well defined starting point and an end point, which you are supplying.

So with this scenario all you need to add is a simple "border: 1px(OR ZERO) solid transparent;" property which will give them something to transition from.

:) Happy Coding!

Comment: Hey. Your suggestion worked very well. At least I am getting much much smoother transition now. I applied border: 3px solid transparent and now the animation is far better. I so far achieved this - https://jsfiddle.net/x3hkuyj5/

Now, if you see it fades out nicely but the border comes in very swiftly. Its like all entire border is applied rather a single side border coming first then second and so on. 

Also, Temani Afif has his own method to achieve what I want. I will use his code if I am not able to do it myself.