# Border is not arranging properly on CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #073146;
}

.box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 350px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: #001e2d;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.box::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    transition: 0.5s;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.box:hover:before{
    left: -50%;
    transform: skewX(-5deg);
}

/* this controls the text inside the box */
.box .content{   
   position: absolute;
   top: 15px;
   left: 15px;
   right: 15px;
   bottom: 15px;
   border: 2px solid #ffeb3b;
   padding: 30px;
   text-align: center;
   box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.box .content h1{
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

.box .content p{
    color: white;
}

.box span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 149%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box span:nth-child(1){
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.box span:nth-child(2){
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.box span:nth-child(3){
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.box span:nth-child(4){
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}

/* setting up one line */
.box span:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #0093ff;
    animation: animate 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0%{
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transform-origin: left;
    }
    50%{
        transform: scaleX(1);
        transform-origin: left;
    }
     50.1%{
        transform: scaleX(1);
        transform-origin: right;
    }
    100%{
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transform-origin: right;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">     
</head>
<body>
        <div class="box">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Some heaading</h1>
                <p>Three border is going perfect but the fourth border is messing up.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I created this CSS but the problem with my CSS is I am not able to get all four borders on end. I am managed to get 3 borders but the fourth border does not seem to fit properly. I was wondering if someone can guide me on how to arrange all four borders blue color at the end of the card. Could some one please guide or help to get proper animation. I would really appreciate some help on this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If your width is fixed，Add `right: -84px; left: auto;` to the second `span`, add style to the fourth span `left: -84px; `

Comment: Strange that didnt work for me. But this did work for me thank you for the huge help. I really appreciate it 

.box span:nth-child(4){
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    left: -170px;
}

.box span:nth-child(2){
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    right: -170px;
    left: auto;
}

Comment: Forgot to say, `width` is changed to `100%`...

Comment: thank you that was a huge help to me. I really appreciate it. I like the better option better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two animation effects, Because the width and height are different, changing the Angle of the animation line is not on the edge.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #073146;
}

.box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 350px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: #001e2d;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.box::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    transition: 0.5s;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.box:hover:before{
    left: -50%;
    transform: skewX(-5deg);
}

/* this controls the text inside the box */
.box .content{   
   position: absolute;
   top: 15px;
   left: 15px;
   right: 15px;
   bottom: 15px;
   border: 2px solid #ffeb3b;
   padding: 30px;
   text-align: center;
   box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.box .content h1{
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

.box .content p{
    color: white;
}

.box span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.box span:nth-child(3){
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.box span:nth-child(4){
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

/* setting up one line */
.box span:nth-child(odd):before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #0093ff;
    animation: animate 4s linear infinite;
}

.box span:nth-child(even):before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #0093ff;
    animation: animate2 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0%{
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transform-origin: left;
    }
    50%{
        transform: scaleX(1);
        transform-origin: left;
    }
     50.1%{
        transform: scaleX(1);
        transform-origin: right;
    }
    100%{
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transform-origin: right;
    }
}

@keyframes animate2 {
    0%{
        transform: scaleY(0);
        transform-origin: bottom;
    }
    50%{
        transform: scaleY(1);
        transform-origin: bottom;
    }
     50.1%{
        transform: scaleY(1);
        transform-origin: top;
    }
    100%{
        transform: scaleY(0);
        transform-origin: top;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">     
</head>
<body>
        <div class="box">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Some heaading</h1>
                <p>Three border is going perfect but the fourth border is messing up.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you this was such a great help. I really appreciate it, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
    .box span:nth-child(2){
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    right: -170px;
    left: auto;
}.box span:nth-child(2){
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    right: -170px;
    left: auto;
}
.box span:nth-child(3){
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.box span:nth-child(4){
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    left: -170px;
}
```

I dont know if this is right or there is any other proper solution but this work for me. Thank you to the commentor to direct me in proper direction. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `width:` property to the animation's full width underneath `.box span`, and then set its second and fourth nth-child's `right:` and `left` properties. Something like:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #073146;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 350px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #001e2d;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.box::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  transition: 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.box:hover:before {
  left: -50%;
  transform: skewX(-5deg);
}

/* this controls the text inside the box */
.box .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #ffeb3b;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.box .content h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.box .content p {
  color: white;
}

.box span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.box span:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: -87px;
  left: auto;
}

.box span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.box span:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  left: -87px;
  right: auto;
}

/* setting up one line */
.box span::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #0093ff;
  animation: animate 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left;
  }

  50% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left;
  }

  50.1% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: right;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Some heaading</h1>
        <p>Three border is going perfect but the fourth border is messing up.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version where you will need few lines of code. The whole animation can be done using background without extra elements:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #073146;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 350px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#0093ff 0 0) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(#0093ff 0 0) 100% 0,
    linear-gradient(#0093ff 0 0) 100% 100%,
    linear-gradient(#0093ff 0 0) 0 100%;
  background-size:100% 2px,2px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color: #001e2d;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow:hidden;
  animation:animate 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate{
   from {
      background-size:0% 2px,2px 0%;
      background-position:0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%;
   }
   50% {
      background-size:100% 2px,2px 100%;
      background-position:0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%;
   }
   50.1% {
      background-size:100% 2px,2px 100%;
      background-position:100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%,0 0;
   }
   100% {
      background-size:0% 2px,2px 0%;
      background-position:100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%,0 0;
   }
}

.box::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  transition: 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform-origin:top;
}

.box:hover:before {
  width:50%;
  transform: skewX(-5deg);
}

.box .content {
  margin:15px;
  border: 2px solid #ffeb3b;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.box .content h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Some heaading</h1>
    <p>Three border is going perfect but the fourth border is messing up.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Related question with a similar effect: [Drawing border colors during a CSS transition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48694894/8620333)